# Print sums of pairs from 1 to 10

Tags: java, lambda

This takes the sum of pairs of numbers from 1 to 10 and outputs the sum, the original numbers, and some connecting text.  Output:

> intArray.length 10
> {Sum of + 1 and 2 =3, Sum of + 3 and 4 =7, Sum of + 5 and 6 =11, Sum of + 7 and 8 =15, Sum of + 9 and 10 =19}

Please see the code below and suggest if this is fine way of doing it and please suggest the changes.

Interface :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SumPrinter {
    void calculateSum(int num1, int num2);
}
```

Class calling the above interface:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class LambdaCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new TreeMap<>();

        SumPrinter sumPrinter = (num1, num2) -> {
            tempMap.put("Sum of + "+num1+" and "+num2+ " ", (num1+num2));
        };

        int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        System.out.println("intArray.length "+intArray.length);

        for (int i=0; i<intArray.length;){
            sumPrinter.calculateSum(intArray[i], intArray[i+1]);
            i = i+2;
        }

        System.out.println(tempMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The code you have provided seems a bit convoluted for such a simple task.

- The interface defined is named `SumPrinter`, but the implementation is storing the result, instead of printing.
- I do not see the need for the array of integers (unless you want to add pairs from an arbitrary `Iterable`). Those numbers can easily be obtained from a simple for-loop or a stream.
- As pointed out in another answer, use string formatting vs string concatenation.

The following code produces a similar output (it could easily be changed to produced the exact output of your code):

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class SumPrintExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 2)
            .limit(5)
            .forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n",
                    i, i + 1, 2 * i + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Code Review, some changes could be applied to your code to improve further its readability:

```
"Sum of + "+num1+" and "+num2+ " "
```

You could adopt the `String.format` method and rewrite this string with the help of a template:

```
String template = "Sum of +%s and %s";
String.format(template, num1, num2)
```

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

You could initialize the array with the line `int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}` erasing the `new` operator.

```
for (int i=0; i<intArray.length;){
    i = i+2;
}
```

You could rewrite the for loop with a step size of 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i +=2) {}
```

About your `SumPrinter` functional interface the built-in [`BiConsumer<T, U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) interface can be applied obtaining the same result:

```
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> sumPrinter = (num1, num2) -> {
    tempMap.put(String.format(template, num1, num2) , (num1 + num2));
};
//other lines and then inside your for loop
sumPrinter.accept(intArray[i], intArray[i + 1]);
```

Putting all these changes together your code can be changed like below:

```
public class LambdaCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new TreeMap<>();

        String template = "Sum of +%s and %s";
        BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> sumPrinter = (num1, num2) -> {
            tempMap.put(String.format(template, num1, num2), (num1 + num2));
        };

        int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        System.out.println("intArray.length " + intArray.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i += 2) {
            sumPrinter.accept(intArray[i], intArray[i + 1]);
        }

        System.out.println(tempMap);

    }

}
```

Comment: @TathagatPandey Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

> This takes the sum of pairs of numbers from 1 to 10 and outputs the sum, the original numbers, and some connecting text.

This requirement is done with saving and later outputting:

```
        tempMap.put("Sum of + "+num1+" and "+num2+ " ", (num1+num2));
```

Using that `tempMap` is not needed. As already mentioned I would output immediately, saving memory and having output immediately.

The problem shows a simple sequence (from n = 1):

```
x      y        x+y
n+0*2  n+1+0*2  2n+1+0*4
n+1*2  n+1*1*2  2n+1+1*4
n+2*2  n+5+2*2  2n+1+2*4
```

This means you have the choice of adding a step value (to what is here x, y, and x+y), or loop over a single variable

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
    System.out.printf("Sum of %d and %d is %d.%n", 1+j*2, 2+j*2, 3+j*4);
}
```

As lambda:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .forEach(j ->
        System.out.printf("Sum of %d and %d is %d.%n", 1+j*2, 2+j*2, 3+j*4));
```

You usage of `TreeMap` cleverly abuses the alphabetical ordering as 9 is the last, 1 digit number with which the text starts.
If also 11 would be added, the order would have been skewed.

```
    Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new TreeMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // More logical
```

Would have solved a more general form. The resulting order is by insert order.

```
    int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] intArray = new int[10];
    Arrays.setAll(intArray, i -> i+1);

    int[] intArray = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).toArray();
```

The IntStream version better uses as IntStream, not first storing in an array:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i <= 10, i -> i + 2)
    .forEach(i -> { // 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new TreeMap<>();
>
>         SumPrinter sumPrinter = (num1, num2) -> {
>             tempMap.put("Sum of + "+num1+" and "+num2+ " ", (num1+num2));
>         };
> ```

Why a `TreeMap`?  The obvious reason would be to make the map sorted, but you don't use the `SortedMap` interface.

More importantly, why use a map at all?  You only use this for display.  But we already have a class to build text for display:  `StringBuilder`.  Consider

```
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        SumPrinter sumPrinter = (num1, num2) -> {
            output.append("Sum of ").append(num1).append(" and ").append(num2)
                .append(" is ").append(num1+num2).append("\n");
        };
```

No extra overhead for inserts.  No need to do a tree traversal to output.  Just a simple string that you can display easily.  It's possible that it might be even more efficient to append the result of a `String.format`.

I changed the format slightly, as I find this more readable.  You could change it back, although you would end up with an extra comma at the end.

Some have argued that you could save space by outputting immediately.  This is true, but you'd have to be adding a really huge batch of numbers for this to matter.  This will output faster in almost all cases.

```
        System.out.print(output.toString());
```